# What is the physics behind a rocket landing on a celestial body with an atmosphere?

Tags: rockets, orbit, landing

I would like to know the different physics concept I would need to land a rocket being in orbit. I know the timing is important to leave it, how can one find this out ? Then how to compute the trajectory it has leaving the orbit and how to compute the change in trajectory with the 'noise' created by the atmosphere. I would be interested in an open loop approach therefore some things can be naturally overlooked. I've come across Tsiolkovsky rocket equation which seems interesting to take the thrust into account but for the rest I'm in a dead. 
Which references would you suggest me to do a complete rocket landing ?

Thank you !

Comment: You may want to start with the planar (2d) atmospheric entry dynamic equations, such as those listed in this question: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22941/differential-equations-for-rocket-launch-in-polar-coordinates

Comment: I guess it depends on how complex and how realistic you want to go with this problem. There have been whole books written about the physics of atmospheric reentry, for example "Hicks, Introduction to Astrodynamic Reentry". Usually you can find simplified forms of the problem in those tomes.